# WPF DataGrid not showing selected items when I open a second window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I open a borderless window with ShowDialog() on mouse right click over WPF datagrid. The aim is to give user chance to add selected items to a list. When the dialog window opens the selected items in DataGrid loose the selected "visuals" (in this case the default blue highlight) until the dialog is closed. How do I get around this so user still has a visual clue as to what they have selected.

Code to open dialog =

```
private void MusicLibrary_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePoint = this.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
        PlayListRClick option = new PlayListRClick();
        option.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
        option.Height = 150;
        option.Width = 100;
        option.Left = mousePoint.X;
        option.Top = mousePoint.Y;
        option.ShowDialog();


        //Get the selected option and add itmes to playlist as needed
        switch (option.choice)
        {
            case RightClickChoice.AddToPlayList:
                IList Items = MusicLibrary.SelectedItems;
                List<MyAlbum> albums = Items.Cast<MyAlbum>().ToList();
                foreach (MyAlbum a in albums)
                {
                    PlayListOb.Add(a);

                }
                break;


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataGrid` will only highlight blue when it has user focus, otherwise it uses a different brush (usally LightGray), so when you dialog opens the `DataGrid` loses focus and the "Blue" brush is removed.

When the `DataGrid` is focused it used `SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey`, and when unfocused it uses `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`

So you could try set the `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` to the `SystemColors.HighlightColor`, this should keep it blue when you open your dialog.

Example:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

### Edit:

For **.NET4.0 and below** you may have to use `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` instead of `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: you can also add this next to it to preserve the foreground :

 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>